# Jade Agents: Cannot connect android device to the jade container

Tags: java, android, agents-jade

This is the container I'm trying to connect:
[image]

And this is the code I have for binding:

```
public void bindService() {
    Log.i("Bind service:", "Starting");
    serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            microRuntimeService = (MicroRuntimeServiceBinder) service;

            Properties pp = new Properties();
            pp.setProperty(Profile.MAIN_HOST, "192.168.1.5");
            pp.setProperty(Profile.MAIN_PORT, "1099");
            pp.setProperty(Profile.JVM, Profile.ANDROID);
            Log.i("Bind service:", "Properties Set");

            microRuntimeService.startAgentContainer(pp, new RuntimeCallback<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    // Split container startup successfull
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Container created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i("Bind service:", "Container creation");
                    microRuntimeService.startAgent(nickname, AndroidAgent.class.getName(), new Object[]{getApplicationContext()}, new RuntimeCallback<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            //Agent succesfully started
                            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Agent created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.i("Bind service:", "Success");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                            //Agent startup error
                            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Agent creation error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.e("Bind service:", "Agent startup error");
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                    // Split container startup error
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Container failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("Bind service:", "Split container startup error");
                }
            });
            ;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            microRuntimeService = null;
        }
    };
    bindService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MicroRuntimeService.class), serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    Log.i("Bind service:", "Binding");
}
```

The code works - I know because my friend used it but in my case my device always falls into this method:

```
@Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                // Split container startup error
```

This is the exception it is showing:

```
jade.imtp.leap.JICP.BIFEDispatcher: Connection error. java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.5 (port 1099): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
09-07 23:06:38.938 19618-20812/com.example.aleksander.localizer E/jade.core.FrontEndContainer: IMTP error jade.core.IMTPException: Error creating the BackEnd.
09-07 23:06:38.940 19618-20812/com.example.aleksander.localizer W/System.err: jade.core.IMTPException: Error creating the BackEnd.
09-07 23:06:38.942 19618-20812/com.example.aleksander.localizer W/System.err:     at jade.imtp.leap.JICP.BIFEDispatcher.createBackEnd(BIFEDispatcher.java:292)
09-07 23:06:38.942 19618-20812/com.example.aleksander.localizer W/System.err:     at jade.imtp.leap.JICP.BIFEDispatcher.getBackEnd(BIFEDispatcher.java:191)
09-07 23:06:38.942 19618-20812/com.example.aleksander.localizer W/System.err:     at jade.core.BackEndWrapper.attach(BackEndWrapper.java:142)
09-07 23:06:38.942 19618-20812/com.example.aleksander.localizer W/System.err:     at jade.core.BackEndWrapper.<init>(BackEndWrapper.java:86)
09-07 23:06:38.943 19618-20812/com.example.aleksander.localizer W/System.err:     at jade.core.FrontEndContainer.start(FrontEndContainer.java:149)
09-07 23:06:38.943 19618-20812/com.example.aleksander.localizer W/System.err:     at jade.core.MicroRuntime.startJADE(MicroRuntime.java:128)
09-07 23:06:38.943 19618-20812/com.example.aleksander.localizer W/System.err:     at jade.android.MicroRuntimeService$1.run(MicroRuntimeService.java:172)
09-07 23:06:38.944 19618-20812/com.example.aleksander.localizer I/jade.android.RuntimeService: Cannot create micro agent container with message: Cannot connect to the platform at 192.168.1.5:1099
```

Is it something with my router or with my code? 
Please help.

Comment: This is a network error.  Is that the right IP?  Its a NAT IP-  are you on the same network?  Are you on wifi or cell data (should be on wifi to be on the same network)?

Comment: Both my laptop and phone are connected to the same network via wifi. I also tested it with my PC connected via cable to my router.

Comment: Are the messages getting through?  Or is your router acting as a firewall?

Comment: I updated my question with more info from logcat. It seems that my router acts like a firewall or sth: first line shows timeout exception

Comment: Sounds like it.  Luckily most routers will allow you to poke a hole in the firewall for a specific port, so long as you're the router admin.

Comment: I tried to map the port in my router and I also tried to work from the wifi access point created on my phone but with no success

Comment: Perhaps I'm doing it wrong, on my Huwaei b593 I enter the mapping but my port is still blocked when I check it through this website [link](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) :(